# Correct instructions for installing MathGeoLib with CMake

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, cmake

I am trying to install MathGeoLib in Ubuntu 14.04 but I have a problem as the instructions I have are for installation on a MAC. I have installed git and cmake.

First I used git to clone the project:

```
git clone https://github.com/juj/MathGeoLib.git
```

Then I selected the linux directory in it:

```
cd MathGeoLib/linux
```

then  I tried to run:

```
./filenames
```

where filenames are the files in that directory (I did that as I didn't know which one was the correct).

Then based on the instructions for MAC I should run:

```
make -j4
sudo make install
```

But I can't install it as I had guessed with these instructions. What should I do? Can anyone explain? As it seems to me it must be a pretty easy procedure for someone that knows how to use CMake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The distribution appears to use the `cmake` build system. A suitable minimal out-of-tree build procedure would be something like

```
mkdir Build && cd Build
cmake ..
```

Then

```
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: Yes  indeed it uses cmake but as that is the first time I try to use something like that your instructions seem to me a little vague as I have no idea how to implement them. Thank you for your answer though. :P

Comment: Did you try the commands? they should work exactly as posted, unless the default installation options don't work for you: you can see additional options by running `cmake -LH ..` or `cmake -LAH ..` from the `Build` directory.

Comment: Yes I did.  They don't work. I am trying to install it and I can't find a way! I have tried everything I could find.

Comment: What part exactly doesn't work? what happens? are there any error messages?

Comment: There is no install file. Also I don't understand where should I run make? In the Build directory?

Comment: Yes you should run it in the `Build` directory (hence the `cd Build` command): `make` should build a library called `libMathGeoLib.a` and if that works, `make install` should copy it to the target directory (by default, `/usr/local/lib`, which is a system directory, hence why you need to run this last step with `sudo`).

Comment: I don't believe it, it worked that way! Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome - sorry it wasn't clear before

Comment: Don't worry, thank you for your help I was desperate. :P